# c++ work around comparison between pointer and integer

Tags: c++

```
do {
    getline (myfile,temp);
    if (temp[0] != "="){
        MyAlbums[i].tracks.push_back(temp);

    }
    else {
        break;
    }
}while(true);
```

gives me this error:

ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]

i am trying to loop through lines in a text file and 'push_pack' if the line does not begin with an "=" equals character. else i want to break out of the loop.

Any help is very much appriceated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if (temp[0] != "="){
```

should be

```
if (temp[0] != '='){
```

The reason is that `temp[0]` is of type `char` (assume `temp` is the string you read in), you should  compare it with char literal `'='` not string literal `"="`. I am assuming that you read `temp` successfully, so you may need to check for that if this is not the case.

**EDIT**(thanks Adam Liss)

strings literals like `"="` are of (`const char *`) type, they are enclosed in double-quotes; individual characters are enclosed in single-quotes. therefore, you have that compile complain message about comparing a `char` (char literal are integers) with `const char *`.

Quoting from here:[IBM C++ documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/macxhelp/v6v81/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.vacpp6m.doc/language/ref/clrc02ccon.htm)

```
C  A character literal has type int.
C++ A character literal that contains only one character has type char, 
which is an integral type.
```

Comment: Clarification (as tacp continues to edit his answer): strings (which are pointers to characters) are enclosed in double-quotes; individual characters are enclosed in single-quotes.  Hence the error message complaining about a pointer.

Comment: thank you for a clean, straight to the point answer. This was very helpful

Comment: @tacp `"="` is an array of two characters (a `const char[2]`), not a pointer. Such arrays get turned into pointers to their first element at the drop of a hat, however, which is why the OP got the error about a pointer.

Comment: The compiler treats an array as a pointer that cannot be reassigned; look at the assembly code and you'll find the address of the memory that contains the '=' character.  That explains the error message.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure that `getline` succeeded.  Evaluate it in a `bool`ean context to figure that out:

```
while (getline(myfile, temp)) {
  /* code goes here */
}
```

instead of

```
do {
  getline(myfile, temp);
  /* code goes here */
} while (true);
```

Never, ever do input without checking if it failed immediately, or you will get really annoying bugs to track down.

Second, make sure `temp` is at least 1 character long.  `temp.size() >= 1` will be `true` if it is safe to do `temp[0]`.  If `getline` ever gives you a `string` of length 0, doing `temp[0]` on it will result in undefined behavior.  Undefined behavior is really annoying to track down, because it can behave completely innocuous in one situation, and then bite you in an unexpected place later.

Third, do `temp[0] != '='` instead of `temp[0] != "="`.  `'='` is a character, `"="` is a buffer of 2 characters the first one is `'='` the second is `'\0'`.  The array of two characters denoted by `"="` is implicitly converted into a pointer to the first character when you try to do `!=`, which then generates an error (because it has no idea how to compare a pointer to a character to a character).